# How to get browser default as well as custom contextmenu within a wrapper javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, contextmenu

i have a requirement where i want to show custom `contextmenu` as well as browser default `contextmenu` within a same **wrapper**

**Note:**  i don't want to change the wrapping or html structure as required for my project

i have a list where i want to show **default browser contextmenu**

```
  var myDefaultContexmenuList = ['defaultcm1','defaultcm2'];
```

the above list may grow

**here is a codepen for better view:** https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/xxVzomB

**here is what i have:**

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", "#contemenuwrapper", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var x = event.clientX;
      var y = event.clientY;
     $(".custom-contextmenuaction").css({ "left": x , "top": y});
     $(".custom-contextmenuaction").show();
}).bind("click", function (event) {
    $(".custom-contextmenuaction").hide();
});

var myDefaultContexmenuList = ['defaultcm1','defaultcm2'];

//how to override i don't know
```

```css
#contemenuwrapper{
/*     height: 600px; */
    background:#ddd;
   padding:3px;
}

.default,.custom{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
      text-align: center;
    line-height: 184px;
    color: #ffff;
    font-size: 44px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.default{
    height:180px;
    background:orange;
}

.custom{
  height: 180px;
  background:orangered;
}

.custom-contextmenuaction{
   width: 120px;
   height:40px;
   background:#000;
   color:#fff;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 6px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Default and custom contextmenu<h4/>


<div id="contemenuwrapper">
    <div class="custom">
        <p>my custom contextmenu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="default" id="defaultcm1">
       <p>Browser default contexmenu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom">
         <p>my custom contextmenu</p>
    </div>
     <div class="default" id="defaultcm2">
       <p>Browser default contextmenu</p>
    </div>
</div>
  
  
 <div class="custom-contextmenuaction" style="display:none;">
   <p>custom menu</p>
 </div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The native context menu of course won’t show, once you have called `event.preventDefault`.

You can fix this in a very trivial way here, if you only react to the event on the elements you actually want to target in the first place.

Replace

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", "#contemenuwrapper", function (event) {
```

with

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", "#contemenuwrapper .custom", function (event) {
```